# Bootstrap accordion doesn't collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have this simple accordion code. On click on the group title, the content is shown as expected. But when I click on another group title the previously opened content doesn't hide.

#### I do not want multiple content to show at the same time and I can't find what I am doing wrong.

Here is my accordion implementation, I don't show you the content because it's dynamically generated and will be source of confusion more that anything else :

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
  // accordion members are generated with a xslt template, in response
  // of a window service
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <div class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{id}">
         // This section is generated dynamically 
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse{id}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
      // the main content is dynamically generated too.
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See the tutorial of bootstrap  **http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion**

Comment: $('.collapse').collapse(); include this..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
// accordion members are generated with a xslt template, in response
// of a window service
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseone">
           // This section is generated dynamically 
        </a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseone" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">
        // the main content is dynamically generated too.
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsetwo">
     // This section is generated dynamically 
        </a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapsetwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">
  // the main content is dynamically generated too.
     </div>
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/966/](http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/966)

in this example it have two group and work properly. one condition is that every one have unique id.

Comment: And by "unique ID", that means the ID needs to be unique across the whole page, not just this accordion. If you've copy-pasted the same thing from the bootstrap website elsewhere, chances are you don't have unique IDs!

Answer (score -1):

Hi I had the same problem. I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it helped me a lot.

I created a function is checking all the time the anchors children of .panel title. I called them #header{{$i}}. So I check if the anchors has the class .collapsed or not. If it has the class .collapsed then I use the bootstrap function: .collapse("hide");

```js
            $(document).ready(function(){
              function checkCollapse{{$i}}(){
                if($('#header{{$i}}').hasClass('collapsed')){

                  $('#collapse{{$i}}').collapse("hide");
                }
                setTimeout(checkCollapse{{$i}}, 100);
              }

                checkCollapse{{$i}}();
            });
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading{{$i}}">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a id='header{{$i}}' role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{$i}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{$i}}">
//Content
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse{{$i}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading{{$i}}">
                <div class="panel-body">
//Content
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

This is the final code i created. Of course you will have to modify it a little bit for your code.

I really hope it can help you.